# Are words like "freaking" and "flippin'" adverbs or adjectives when used like this?

Tags: parts-of-speech

As far as I understand it a present participle used like the one in the example ould be functionally an adjective

> The barking dog.

I am wondering about intensifying words like "freaking" or "flipping" or "god damn"

> Take the flippin' train.

To me, they don't convey very much about the noun but rather something about the speakers thoughts that go beyond the statement. As such they feel just the same as their adverb-instances

> Just freaking go.

Seeing that "freaking" does not have the usual "-ly" ending, I have the following questions.

- Is the first use really an adjective?
- Are intensifying words categorized totally disregarding their semantic function?
- What are they?
- What are they in combination with verbs?
- If adverb, why not "-ly".

Comment: They're all adjectives, still. Only they're used rather loosely, mostly as non-sense fillers or bland intensifiers (intensifiers without an intensifying sense in themselves). There's neither syntactical nor semantic difference in these structures from *The barking dog*.

Comment: @Kris.. any literature backup? Because without it I cannot agree that there is no semantic difference. "Barking" is what the dog does, "freaking" is "flippin'" is what I think about the discussion.

Comment: Check out usage examples in literature.

Comment: It makes no sense to class 'freaking' here as an adjective.

Comment: Why would people **often** think adverbs have to take *-ly*? If you dig **deep**, you’ll see that that’s **unlikely** to the point of being **silly**.

Comment: **freaking** is a 'safe' substitute for a curse word with most of the same letters.  Since it modifies a noun, sure it is an adjective.  It distinguishes this dog from other, non-freaking, animals.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, slang, profanity, and this sort of muted or pseudo-profanity don't necessarily follow the conventional rules of grammar.

When these sort of words are used as adjectives, they are at least grammatically consistent. If we assume that "to freak" is a verb that presumably means something bad or unpleasant, then, "Make your freaking dog stop barking" makes some sense: the speaker want to express that the dog is doing something unpleasant, so if "to freak" is bad, then describing the dog as a "freaking dog" means he is doing something bad. Of course when taken more literally, it still doesn't make much sense. I presume when people say "to freak" they are using that as a euphemism for another word that begins and ends with the same letters and that refers to sexual activity, and the dog in question is probably not engaging in sex. The train but surely is not.

As an adverb -- "Just freaking go", it makes no grammatical sense. You could say, "Just go freakingly", but what does that actually mean? Sometimes people say, "Go freak yourself", which again is unlikely to resolve the immediate issue or be physically possible, but at least is grammatically coherent.

Of course we don't normally expect insults and profanity to make literal sense. They're just words added to a sentence to express anger or dislike, or to establish yourself as one of the cool people who use such words. The f-word, in particular, rarely makes sense in context if interpreted literally.

Most slang words, whether mild or vulgar, are not being used for their literal meaning, but rather are used to mean either "bad" or "good". There are probably dozens or hundreds of slang words in use at any given time that all mean "bad" or "good", from "groovy" to "cool" to "phat", etc.

Comment: How are those sentences different from *The barking dog*? I could as well have said *The freaking dog* or *The stupid dog* in the same structure.

Comment: Thanks for our answer. I suppose that there must be some consenus as to what "god damn" or "freaking" in front of a noun is. I was more interested in that, than in how much sense it makes. Do you have any literature or anything?

Comment: @Emmanuel As an adjective "freaking" makes grammatical sense, just like "barking" or "sleeping", etc. We routinely turn a verb into an adjective by adding -ing. "The damn dog" should be "The damned dog" to be grammatically correct. Though again, I doubt the speaker is really commenting on the future of the dog's soul. A "barking dog" is a dog who is presently or habitually engaged in barking; a "kicked dog" is a dog who has been the target of a kick. Similarly for other verbs used as adjectives.

Comment: If an approach like 'if we can fit an obvious Y there instead of the X it must be the same part of speech' is considered acceptable, we might as well stop analysing English. 'He marked the answer wrong' =/= 'He marked the answer wrongly'. In fact, 'Flying planes can be dangerous' may even be different from 'Flying planes can be dangerous', with one a (participial) adjective usage of 'flying' and one the gerund. Here, 'Take the flippin' train' is rather crudely emphasising the recommended mode of transport, or the recommended course of action. 'Just get on with it: take the train! ...

Comment: ... This makes the 'flippin' an emphasising pragmatic marker; it's certainly neither an adjective (not "modifying" 'train' with any meaning of the word worth considering) nor an adverb. 'Barking' is a standard participial adjective here. 'Freaking' here is another pragmatic marker, slang emphasiser.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I certainly do not say that if X can be substituted for Y in a sentence than both must be the same part of speech! I agree, that would be absurd. "I called him loudly." "Loudly" is an adverb. "I called him Fred." Therefore Fred must be an adverb? But consider a more conventional word for these examples. Suppose I said,  "Get on the stupid train!" Of course "stupid" here doesn't make much literal sense. It is meaningless to discuss the intelligence of a train. But nevertheless, grammatically, "stupid" is an adjective modifying "train". Yes, what I really mean is probably ...

Comment: ... something more like, "Stop being stupid and get on the train." But you can't analyze grammar on the basis of the true, inner meaning that the speaker intended to convey.

Comment: We live in hope. Determiners were once classed as adjectives, until the craziness of lumping them with such dissimilar entities was generally accepted. Words next to a noun that don't really have any semantic connection with it are so peripheral I'd say they're outside.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth... why don't you make those 3 comments into an answer. I'd probably accept it.